# SQL script takes long time to run

Tags: c#, sql, enterprise-library

I'm currently using Microsoft Enterprise Library Data Access 5.0 to execute a stored procedure.

```
Database myDatabase = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase();
using (DbCommand command = myDatabase.GetStoredProcCommand("myStoredProc"))
{
   //Add parameters here
   using (IDataReader dataReader = myDatabase.ExecuteReader(command))
   {
      while (dataReader.Read())
      {
      }
   }
}
```

Everything works however it takes a long time to run. When I turn on SQL Profiler, I can see the stored procedure takes about 50 seconds to run. However, if i take that same scripts from the Profiler and run it inside SQL Management Studio, it only takes about 480 miliseconds to return all the rows.

Has anyone run into this issue? Why is there a big difference?

Comment: does it change if you remove the while loop?

Comment: i have to try that and see.

Comment: This question comes up a couple of times a week on the MSDN SQL forum; it must be a duplicate here as well. I forget the exact cause, but it is a default setting that needs to be tweaked.

Comment: Is one of your parameters is a string?  It may be the infamous nvarchar parameter to varchar index problem (or is the other way around?)

Comment: Yes the parameter is string varchar(150). And added like this: myDatabase.AddInParameter(command, "@Param", DbType.String, value);

Comment: FYI, removing the while loop doesn't help.

Comment: Did you run the `SET` statements from the profile session that are executed when your app connects? Run these into SSMS and then execute the proc again. See if that recreates the behaviour. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9134739/tsql-error-in-net-but-not-in-ssms/9135498#9135498

Comment: After further testing, the performance is improved after I make a "meaningless" change to the Stored Procedure (adding a blank space). Not sure how this affects the execution time.

Answer (score 1):

Could easily be [Parameter Sniffing](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/parameter-sniffing/).

Comment: Yes, that's another good possible cause; not the one  was thinking of.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your string parameter type to `DbType.AnsiString` and see if that helps.
The problem can be that if the database column is varchar(...) and has an index and the parameter matching that column is nvarchar(...) then SQL Server ignores the index and does a table scan.
The solution is to force the parameter to type AnsiString so that SQL Server uses the index.